# How to get Student Details SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

- i have table student with ID,SID,CHECKID,DATE
- here ID : tableID(auto increment), SID : studentID ,CHECKID : 0/1(i.e. IN/OUT), DATE.
- when student entered into class room he will save daily attendance by card.
- i have data is

  ID   SID   CHECKID    DATE

  ---  ---  --------    -----

  0    101   0           04-10-2013 10:00:00

  1    101   1           04-10-2013 11:30:00

  2    101   0           04-10-2013 14:15:00
- i tried query like :

  **select DISTINCT SID,MAX(DATE),CHECKID from student where SID='101' group by SID**
- then i got results as two records.
- i need record is max date(i.e. recent record of particular student ) like : 3rd record only.
- any help.thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? You tagged both but they are very different databases.

Comment: thanks for replay @ Brian DeMilia. Using Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest approach is probably to use an analytic function:

```
select *
  from (select s.*,
               row_number() over(partition by sid order by date desc) as rn
          from student s)
 where rn = 1
```

Another way is a correlated subquery:

```
select *
  from student s
 where date = (select max(x.date) from student x where x.sid = s.sid)
```

Another way is to join into an inline view:

```
select s.*
  from student s
  join (select sid, max(date) as sid_last_date from student group by sid) v
    on s.sid = v.sid
   and s.date = v.sid_last_date
```

Comment: thanks its worked for me when i added  **select *
  from student s
 where date = (select max(x.date) from student x where x.sid = s.sid) and s.sid='101'**

Comment: @kks I didn't realize you were interested in a particular student, yes just add to the where clause to filter in on specific people. The above queries will filter in on the last effective dated row for each student. Afterward you can freely filter in on anything else.